# Can I post image to Facebook from my app without installing Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-share

I am using Facebook SDK (version 4.28) in my Android app. **I want to share image to Facebook without installing Facebook app**.

I am using `SharePhoto` and `SharePhotoContent` classes to build request. When I call `ShareDialog.show(activity, shareContent)`, it gives me an error in `onError(FacebookException)`. Here is the error message:

> {FacebookGraphResponseException: could not construct request body httpResponseCode: -1, facebookErrorCode: -1, facebookErrorType: null, message: could not construct request body}

I done google with this error but no luck :(

Please someone let me know if I'm missing something or photo cannot be shared to Facebook without installing Facebook app.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can debug line in Facebook SDK in `GraphRequest.toHttpConnection(1051)` when throw this `FacebookGraphResponseException` and lock to first exception.

In my case, it was

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: content://com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider